# Trying to retrieve data using JPA Query Annotation

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to execute a query using the @Query annotation from JPA, like this:

```
public interface UserResultRepository extends CrudRepository<UserResult, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT name, score FROM quizzapp.user_result result WHERE result.quiz_id = :quizId", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserResult> listResultsForExport(@Param("quizId") String quizId); 

}
```

But i'm getting the following message from the console:

`java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.`

Here's the entity structure inside the database:

[Entity in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELcrr.png)

I first tried to use without the `nativeQuery`, but i got a different error saying that i should have a converter to the data that was being retrieved from the database, and then i did it again using the `nativeQuery`, and now i'm facing this different error.

Comment: `UserResult` has an id property?

Comment: Could you share `@Entity` class that you have in java code ?

Comment: Your entity isn't mapped to the data correctly. This is a native query that is only returning 2 fields (name and score) while your entity requires an ID column as well. If you use JPQL query, maybe something like Query(value = "select resultfrom UserResult result where result.quizId = :quizId"), just be sure you have a java 'quizId' property

Comment: I've tried using as you said @Chris and it worked, thanks in advance to everyone that answered too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure UserResult entity has an attribute named id, like this :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private String id;
```